# Electron command opens file asscociation menu in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

I am new to Windows 10. I am building [Screencat](https://github.com/maxogden/screencat) app for Windows. But when I run the "npm start" in console, I get the below popup asking for how I want to open the js file.

Is it possible to run electron apps in Windows 10?

[image: File association menu]

Answer (score 0):

For Screencat `npm start` runs the command `electron electron.js`. It seems that your OS is not recognising `electron` as a valid command.

Did you follow the instructions (https://github.com/maxogden/screencat#building-the-app) for Windows completely? In particular, installing C++ and installing and running `electron-rebuild`.

> **You will need Visual studio C++ installed** so you can build the native modules. Here are instructions for cmd.exe
>
> ```
>  git clone https://github.com/maxogden/screencat.git
>  cd screencat
>  npm install
>  npm install electron-rebuild
>  .\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
>  npm start
> ```